# How to modify shadow "position" for cursors in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cursor, mouse-cursor

I would like to modify the location / rendering of the cursor shadow in Windows 10 such that it is not at it's current offset while enabled.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [turning the cursor shadow on and off](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-show-mouse-pointer-shadow-in-windows-10.html), each cursor can be edited to define the [alpha channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550467/shadow-for-custom-mouse-cursor), the area which will be shadowed. Use an icon editor, such as free [Greenfish icon editor pro](http://greenfishsoftware.org/gfie.php#apage), shown below.

[image: Greenfish icon editor pro]

Remember in addition to setting the alpha channel, to set the *hot spot*, the specific pixel to which the cursor points

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off the shadow on the cursor ( there’s a setting for it under the window effects settings) and set up a custom cursor with the shadow in the right position?

Not ideal but it’s something.